# Set up a Stomp client in android with Spring framework in server side

Tags: android, spring, websocket, stomp

I am developing an android application that exchanges data with a jetty server configured in Spring. To obtain a more dynamic android application, i am trying to use WebSocket protocol with Stomp messages.

In order to realize this stuff, i config a web socket message broker in spring :

```
@Configuration
//@EnableScheduling
@ComponentScan(
        basePackages="project.web",
        excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type= FilterType.ANNOTATION, value = Configuration.class)
)
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/message");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/client");
    }
}
```

and a `SimpMessageSendingOperations` in Spring controller to send message from server to client :

```
@Controller
public class MessageAddController {
    private final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(MessageAddController.class);

    private SimpMessageSendingOperations messagingTemplate;

    private UserManager userManager;

    private MessageManager messageManager;

    @Autowired
    public MessageAddController(SimpMessageSendingOperations messagingTemplate, 
            UserManager userManager, MessageManager messageManager){
        this.messagingTemplate = messagingTemplate;
        this.userManager = userManager;
        this.messageManager = messageManager;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/Message/Add")
    @ResponseBody
    public SimpleMessage addFriendship(
            @RequestParam String content,
            @RequestParam Long otherUser_id
    ){
        if(log.isInfoEnabled())
            log.info("Execute MessageAdd action");
        SimpleMessage simpleMessage;

        try{
            User curentUser = userManager.getCurrentUser();
            User otherUser = userManager.findUser(otherUser_id);

            Message message = new Message();
            message.setContent(content);
            message.setUserSender(curentUser);
            message.setUserReceiver(otherUser);

            messageManager.createMessage(message);          
            Message newMessage = messageManager.findLastMessageCreated();

            messagingTemplate.convertAndSend( 
                    "/message/add", newMessage);//send message through websocket

            simpleMessage = new SimpleMessage(null, newMessage);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if(log.isErrorEnabled())
                log.error("A problem of type : " + e.getClass() 
                        + " has occured, with message : " + e.getMessage());
            simpleMessage = new SimpleMessage(
                            new SimpleException(e.getClass(), e.getMessage()), null);
        }
        return simpleMessage;
    }
}
```

When i test this configuration in a web browser with stomp.js, I haven't any problem : messages are perfectly exchanged between web browser and Jetty server. The JavaScript code using for web browser test :

```
    var stompClient = null;

    function setConnected(connected) {
        document.getElementById('connect').disabled = connected;
        document.getElementById('disconnect').disabled = !connected;
        document.getElementById('conversationDiv').style.visibility = connected ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
        document.getElementById('response').innerHTML = '';
    }

    function connect() {
        stompClient = Stomp.client("ws://YOUR_IP/client");         
        stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
            setConnected(true);
            stompClient.subscribe('/message/add', function(message){
                showMessage(JSON.parse(message.body).content);
            });
        });
    }

    function disconnect() {
        stompClient.disconnect();
        setConnected(false);
        console.log("Disconnected");
    }


    function showMessage(message) {
        var response = document.getElementById('response');
        var p = document.createElement('p');
        p.style.wordWrap = 'break-word';
        p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(message));
        response.appendChild(p);
    }
```

Problems occur when i try to use stomp in Android with libraries like gozirra, activemq-stomp or others : most of time, connection with server doesn't work. My app stop to run and, after a few minutes, i have the following message in logcat : `java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "ws://192.168.1.39/client": No address associated with hostname`, and i don't understand why. Code using Gozzira library which manages the stomp appeal in my android activity :

```
private void stomp_test() {
    String ip = "ws://192.172.6.39/client";
    int port = 8080;

    String channel = "/message/add";
    Client c;

    try {
        c = new Client( ip, port, "", "" );
        Log.i("Stomp", "Connection established");
        c.subscribe( channel, new Listener() {
            public void message( Map header, String message ) {
                Log.i("Stomp", "Message received!!!");
              }
        });

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Log.e("Stomp", ex.getMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace();

    } catch (LoginException ex) {
        Log.e("Stomp", ex.getMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e("Stomp", ex.getMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

After some research, i found that most persons who want to use stomp over websocket with Java Client use ActiveMQ server, like in this [site](http://aredko.blogspot.fr/2013/06/easy-messaging-with-stomp-over.html). But spring tools are very simple to use and it will be cool if i could keep my server layer as is it now. Someone would know how to use stomp java (Android) in client side with Spring configuration in server side?

Comment: you didn't talk about how you are managing threads.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I achieve to use stomp over web socket with Android and spring server.

To do such a thing, i used a web socket library : werbench (follow this [link](https://github.com/pelotoncycle/weberknecht) to download it). To install, I used the maven command `mvn install` and i got back the jar in my local repository. Then, I need to add a stomp layer on the basic web socket one, but i couldn't find any stomp library in java which could manage stomp over web socket (I had to give up gozzira). So I create my own one (with stomp.js like model). Don't hesitate to ask me if you want take a look at it, but i realized it very quickly so it can not manage as much as stomp.js. Then, i need to realize an authentication with my spring server. To achieve it, i followed the indication of [this site](http://blogs.burnsidedigital.com/2012/11/how-to-use-ssl-and-session-cookies-with-spring-for-android/). when i get back the JSESSIONID cookie, I had just need to declare an header with this cookie in the instantiation of a werbench  web socket in my stomp "library".

EDIT :
this is the main class in this library, the one which manage the stomp over web socket connection :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import android.util.Log;
import de.roderick.weberknecht.WebSocket;
import de.roderick.weberknecht.WebSocketEventHandler;
import de.roderick.weberknecht.WebSocketMessage;

public class Stomp {

    private static final String TAG = Stomp.class.getSimpleName();

    public static final int CONNECTED = 1;//Connection completely established
    public static final int NOT_AGAIN_CONNECTED = 2;//Connection process is ongoing
    public static final int DECONNECTED_FROM_OTHER = 3;//Error, no more internet connection, etc.
    public static final int DECONNECTED_FROM_APP = 4;//application explicitely ask for shut down the connection 

    private static final String PREFIX_ID_SUBSCIPTION = "sub-";
    private static final String ACCEPT_VERSION_NAME = "accept-version";
    private static final String ACCEPT_VERSION = "1.1,1.0";
    private static final String COMMAND_CONNECT = "CONNECT";
    private static final String COMMAND_CONNECTED = "CONNECTED";
    private static final String COMMAND_MESSAGE = "MESSAGE";
    private static final String COMMAND_RECEIPT = "RECEIPT";
    private static final String COMMAND_ERROR = "ERROR";
    private static final String COMMAND_DISCONNECT = "DISCONNECT";
    private static final String COMMAND_SEND = "SEND";
    private static final String COMMAND_SUBSCRIBE = "SUBSCRIBE";
    private static final String COMMAND_UNSUBSCRIBE = "UNSUBSCRIBE";
    private static final String SUBSCRIPTION_ID = "id";
    private static final String SUBSCRIPTION_DESTINATION = "destination";
    private static final String SUBSCRIPTION_SUBSCRIPTION = "subscription";


    private static final Set<String> VERSIONS = new HashSet<String>();
    static {
        VERSIONS.add("V1.0");
        VERSIONS.add("V1.1");
        VERSIONS.add("V1.2");
    }

    private WebSocket websocket;

    private int counter;

    private int connection;

    private Map<String, String> headers;

    private int maxWebSocketFrameSize;

    private Map<String, Subscription> subscriptions;

    private ListenerWSNetwork networkListener;

    /**
     * Constructor of a stomp object. Only url used to set up a connection with a server can be instantiate
     * 
     * @param url
     *      the url of the server to connect with
     */
    public Stomp(String url, Map<String,String> headersSetup, ListenerWSNetwork stompStates){       
        try {
            this.websocket = new WebSocket(new URI(url), null, headersSetup);
            this.counter = 0;

            this.headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            this.maxWebSocketFrameSize = 16 * 1024;
            this.connection = NOT_AGAIN_CONNECTED;
            this.networkListener = stompStates;
            this.networkListener.onState(NOT_AGAIN_CONNECTED);
            this.subscriptions = new HashMap<String, Subscription>();

            this.websocket.setEventHandler(new WebSocketEventHandler() {        
                @Override
                public void onOpen(){
                    if(Stomp.this.headers != null){                                         
                        Stomp.this.headers.put(ACCEPT_VERSION_NAME, ACCEPT_VERSION);

                        transmit(COMMAND_CONNECT, Stomp.this.headers, null);

                        Log.d(TAG, "...Web Socket Openned");
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onMessage(WebSocketMessage message) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "<<< " + message.getText());
                    Frame frame = Frame.fromString(message.getText());
                    boolean isMessageConnected = false;

                    if(frame.getCommand().equals(COMMAND_CONNECTED)){
                        Stomp.this.connection = CONNECTED;
                        Stomp.this.networkListener.onState(CONNECTED);

                        Log.d(TAG, "connected to server : " + frame.getHeaders().get("server"));
                        isMessageConnected = true;

                    } else if(frame.getCommand().equals(COMMAND_MESSAGE)){
                        String subscription = frame.getHeaders().get(SUBSCRIPTION_SUBSCRIPTION);
                        ListenerSubscription onReceive = Stomp.this.subscriptions.get(subscription).getCallback();

                        if(onReceive != null){
                            onReceive.onMessage(frame.getHeaders(), frame.getBody());
                        } else{
                            Log.e(TAG, "Error : Subscription with id = " + subscription + " had not been subscribed");
                            //ACTION TO DETERMINE TO MANAGE SUBCRIPTION ERROR
                        }

                    } else if(frame.getCommand().equals(COMMAND_RECEIPT)){
                        //I DON'T KNOW WHAT A RECEIPT STOMP MESSAGE IS

                    } else if(frame.getCommand().equals(COMMAND_ERROR)){
                        Log.e(TAG, "Error : Headers = " + frame.getHeaders() + ", Body = " + frame.getBody());
                        //ACTION TO DETERMINE TO MANAGE ERROR MESSAGE

                    } else {

                    }

                    if(isMessageConnected)
                        Stomp.this.subscribe();
                }

                @Override
                public void onClose(){
                    if(connection == DECONNECTED_FROM_APP){
                        Log.d(TAG, "Web Socket disconnected");
                        disconnectFromApp();
                    } else{
                        Log.w(TAG, "Problem : Web Socket disconnected whereas Stomp disconnect method has never "
                                + "been called.");
                        disconnectFromServer();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onPing() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onPong() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error : " + e.getMessage());                
                }
            });
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Send a message to server thanks to websocket
     * 
     * @param command
     *      one of a frame property, see {@link Frame} for more details
     * @param headers
     *      one of a frame property, see {@link Frame} for more details
     * @param body
     *      one of a frame property, see {@link Frame} for more details
     */
    private void transmit(String command, Map<String, String> headers, String body){
        String out = Frame.marshall(command, headers, body);
        Log.d(TAG, ">>> " + out);
        while (true) {
            if (out.length() > this.maxWebSocketFrameSize) {
                this.websocket.send(out.substring(0, this.maxWebSocketFrameSize));
                out = out.substring(this.maxWebSocketFrameSize);
            } else {
                this.websocket.send(out);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Set up a web socket connection with a server
     */
    public void connect(){
        if(this.connection != CONNECTED){
            Log.d(TAG, "Opening Web Socket...");
            try{
                this.websocket.connect();
            } catch (Exception e){
                Log.w(TAG, "Impossible to establish a connection : " + e.getClass() + ":" + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * disconnection come from the server, without any intervention of client side. Operations order is very important
     */
    private void disconnectFromServer(){
        if(this.connection == CONNECTED){
            this.connection = DECONNECTED_FROM_OTHER;
            this.websocket.close();
            this.networkListener.onState(this.connection);
        }
    }

    /**
     * disconnection come from the app, because the public method disconnect was called
     */
    private void disconnectFromApp(){
        if(this.connection == DECONNECTED_FROM_APP){
            this.websocket.close();
            this.networkListener.onState(this.connection);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Close the web socket connection with the server. Operations order is very important
     */
    public void disconnect(){
        if(this.connection == CONNECTED){
            this.connection = DECONNECTED_FROM_APP;
            transmit(COMMAND_DISCONNECT, null, null);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Send a simple message to the server thanks to the body parameter
     * 
     * 
     * @param destination
     *      The destination through a Stomp message will be send to the server
     * @param headers
     *      headers of the message
     * @param body
     *      body of a message
     */
    public void send(String destination, Map<String,String> headers, String body){
        if(this.connection == CONNECTED){
            if(headers == null)
                headers = new HashMap<String, String>();

            if(body == null)
                body = "";

            headers.put(SUBSCRIPTION_DESTINATION, destination);

            transmit(COMMAND_SEND, headers, body);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Allow a client to send a subscription message to the server independently of the initialization of the web socket.
     * If connection have not been already done, just save the subscription
     * 
     * @param subscription
     *      a subscription object
     */
    public void subscribe(Subscription subscription){
        subscription.setId(PREFIX_ID_SUBSCIPTION + this.counter++);
        this.subscriptions.put(subscription.getId(), subscription);

        if(this.connection == CONNECTED){   
            Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();            
            headers.put(SUBSCRIPTION_ID, subscription.getId());
            headers.put(SUBSCRIPTION_DESTINATION, subscription.getDestination());

            subscribe(headers);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Subscribe to a Stomp channel, through messages will be send and received. A message send from a determine channel
     * can not be receive in an another.
     *
     */
    private void subscribe(){
        if(this.connection == CONNECTED){
            for(Subscription subscription : this.subscriptions.values()){
                Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();            
                headers.put(SUBSCRIPTION_ID, subscription.getId());
                headers.put(SUBSCRIPTION_DESTINATION, subscription.getDestination());

                subscribe(headers);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Send the subscribe to the server with an header
     * @param headers
     *      header of a subscribe STOMP message
     */
    private void subscribe(Map<String, String> headers){
        transmit(COMMAND_SUBSCRIBE, headers, null);
    }

    /**
     * Destroy a subscription with its id
     * 
     * @param id
     *      the id of the subscription. This id is automatically setting up in the subscribe method
     */
    public void unsubscribe(String id){
        if(this.connection == CONNECTED){
            Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put(SUBSCRIPTION_ID, id);

            this.subscriptions.remove(id);
            this.transmit(COMMAND_UNSUBSCRIBE, headers, null);
        }
    }
}
```

This one is the Frame of a Stomp message :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Frame {
//  private final static String CONTENT_LENGTH = "content-length";

    private String command;
    private Map<String, String> headers;
    private String body;

    /**
     * Constructor of a Frame object. All parameters of a frame can be instantiate
     * 
     * @param command
     * @param headers
     * @param body
     */
    public Frame(String command, Map<String, String> headers, String body){
        this.command = command;     
        this.headers = headers != null ? headers : new HashMap<String, String>();
        this.body = body != null ? body : "";
    }

    public String getCommand(){
        return command;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getHeaders(){
        return headers;
    }

    public String getBody(){
        return body;
    }

    /**
     * Transform a frame object into a String. This method is copied on the objective C one, in the MMPReactiveStompClient
     * library
     * @return a frame object convert in a String
     */
    private String toStringg(){
        String strLines = this.command;
        strLines += Byte.LF;
        for(String key : this.headers.keySet()){
            strLines += key + ":" + this.headers.get(key);
            strLines += Byte.LF;
        }
        strLines += Byte.LF;
        strLines += this.body;
        strLines += Byte.NULL;

        return strLines;
    }

    /**
     * Create a frame from a received message. This method is copied on the objective C one, in the MMPReactiveStompClient
     * library
     * 
     * @param data
     *  a part of the message received from network, which represented a frame
     * @return
     *  An object frame
     */
    public static Frame fromString(String data){
        List<String> contents = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(data.split(Byte.LF)));

        while(contents.size() > 0 && contents.get(0).equals("")){
            contents.remove(0);
        }

        String command = contents.get(0);
        Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String body = "";

        contents.remove(0);
        boolean hasHeaders = false;
        for(String line : contents){
            if(hasHeaders){
                for(int i=0; i < line.length(); i++){
                    Character c = line.charAt(i);
                    if(!c.equals('\0'))
                        body += c;
                }
            } else{
                if(line.equals("")){
                    hasHeaders = true;
                } else {
                    String[] header = line.split(":");
                    headers.put(header[0], header[1]);
                }
            }
        }
        return new Frame(command, headers, body);   
    }

//    No need this method, a single frame will be always be send because body of the message will never be excessive
//    /**
//     * Transform a message received from server in a Set of objects, named frame, manageable by java
//     * 
//     * @param datas
//     *        message received from network
//     * @return
//     *        a Set of Frame
//     */
//    public static Set<Frame> unmarshall(String datas){
//      String data;
//      String[] ref = datas.split(Byte.NULL + Byte.LF + "*");//NEED TO VERIFY THIS PARAMETER
//      Set<Frame> results = new HashSet<Frame>();
//      
//      for (int i = 0, len = ref.length; i < len; i++) {
//            data = ref[i];
//            
//            if ((data != null ? data.length() : 0) > 0){
//              results.add(unmarshallSingle(data));//"unmarshallSingle" is the old name method for "fromString"
//            }
//        }         
//      return results;
//    }

    /**
     * Create a frame with based fame component and convert them into a string
     * 
     * @param command
     * @param headers
     * @param body
     * @return  a frame object convert in a String, thanks to <code>toStringg()</code> method
     */
    public static String marshall(String command, Map<String, String> headers, String body){
        Frame frame = new Frame(command, headers, body);
        return frame.toStringg();
    }

    private class Byte {
        public static final String LF = "\n";
        public static final String NULL = "\0";
    }
}
```

This one is an object used to establish a subscription via the stomp protocol :

```
public class Subscription {

    private String id;

    private String destination;

    private ListenerSubscription callback;

    public Subscription(String destination, ListenerSubscription callback){
        this.destination = destination;
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDestination() {
        return destination;
    }

    public ListenerSubscription getCallback() {
        return callback;
    }
}
```

At least, there are two interfaces used as the "Run" java class, to listen web socket network and a given subscription canal

```
public interface ListenerWSNetwork {
    public void onState(int state);
}

import java.util.Map;
public interface ListenerSubscription {
    public void onMessage(Map<String, String> headers, String body);
}
```

For more information, don't hesitate to ask me.

Comment: You should always post your solution.

Comment: Could you please provide an example about how to subscribe to ws service?

Comment: Hi, How do you manage to run Spring over Cross domain (mobile devices). I am implementing a solution using Spring with Sockjs and JWT tokens but Sockjs fallback into iframe because (I think) the client is running in a different domain.

Comment: @Eperrin95 `i followed the indication of this site. when i get back the JSESSIONID cookie,` the link is dead

Comment: Can you provide link to the client please?

Answer (score 11):

My implementation of STOMP protocol for android (or plain java) with RxJava https://github.com/NaikSoftware/StompProtocolAndroid. Tested on STOMP server with SpringBoot.
Simple example (with [retrolambda](https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda)):

```
private StompClient mStompClient;

 // ...

 mStompClient = Stomp.over(WebSocket.class, "ws://localhost:8080/app/hello/websocket");
 mStompClient.connect();

 mStompClient.topic("/topic/greetings").subscribe(topicMessage -> {
     Log.d(TAG, topicMessage.getPayload());
 });

 mStompClient.send("/app/hello", "My first STOMP message!");

 // ...

 mStompClient.disconnect();
```

Add the following classpath in project :

```
  classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.2.0'
```

Add the following thing in your app build.gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'

android {
       .............
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}


  dependencies {
      ............................
    compile 'org.java-websocket:Java-WebSocket:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.github.NaikSoftware:StompProtocolAndroid:1.1.5'
}
```

All working asynchronously! You can call `connect()` after `subscribe()` and `send()`, messages will be pushed to queue.

Additional features:

- extra HTTP headers for handshake query (for passing auth token or other)
- you can implement own transport for library, just implement interface ConnectionProvider
- subscribe connection lifecycle events (connected, closed, error)

For Example :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private StompClient mStompClient;
    public static  final String TAG="StompClient";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button view = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        view.setOnClickListener(e->  new LongOperation().execute(""));


    }


        private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        private StompClient mStompClient;
        String TAG="LongOperation";
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            mStompClient = Stomp.over(WebSocket.class, "ws://localhost:8080/app/hello/websocket");
            mStompClient.connect();

            mStompClient.topic("/topic/greetings").subscribe(topicMessage -> {
                Log.d(TAG, topicMessage.getPayload());
            });

            mStompClient.send("/app/hello", "My first STOMP message!").subscribe();


            mStompClient.lifecycle().subscribe(lifecycleEvent -> {
                switch (lifecycleEvent.getType()) {

                    case OPENED:
                        Log.d(TAG, "Stomp connection opened");
                        break;

                    case ERROR:
                        Log.e(TAG, "Error", lifecycleEvent.getException());
                        break;

                    case CLOSED:
                        Log.d(TAG, "Stomp connection closed");
                        break;
                }
            });
            return "Executed";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        }

    }
}
```

Add Internet permission in manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: How do you reconnect with your library? Thanks.

Comment: can't use it. everytime StompClient receive message, it always disconnected.

Comment: @Raizal call connect() method after subscibe

Comment: where are you put this line? `  classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.2.0'`? build.gradle?

Comment: In project-level gradle `buildscript>dependencies`

Comment: @NickolaySavchenko its not working forme, but i dont know why, i can connect to `ws://localhost:61614` but not `ws://localhost:8080` and i see from https://github.com/NaikSoftware/StompProtocolAndroid, its setup the endpoint to `/hello`, but from that code, he was connect to `Stomp.over(WebSocket.class, "ws://localhost:8080/app/hello/websocket");`
can you help me? i don't know why, i cannot connect to `ws://localhost:8080`

Comment: @NickolaySavchenko hi,, will you join this chat room please ? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136809/stomp-with-spring-web-socket

Comment: if server send, it display :-
"D/WebSocketsConnectionProvider: Emit STOMP message:                                                                                      destination:/topic/online/                                                                                        
message-id:ID:Laptop-Jiban-63222-1512979632616-18:1:1:1:1                                                                                             timestamp:1512981478081
Enter some text here for the message body"


 Not executing Log.d(TAG, topicMessage.getPayload()); block

Comment: Hi.. I am getting error ie. Failed to resolve: compile 'com.github.NaikSoftware:StompProtocolAndroid:1.1.5'

Answer (score 2):

Perfect solution Eperrin thank you. I would like fill the complete solution e.g. in your Activity/Service phase you call `connection` method of course doesn't in MainThread.

```
private void connection() {
        Map<String,String> headersSetup = new HashMap<String,String>();
        Stomp stomp = new Stomp(hostUrl, headersSetup, new ListenerWSNetwork() {
            @Override
            public void onState(int state) {
            }
        });
        stomp.connect();
        stomp.subscribe(new Subscription(testUrl, new ListenerSubscription() {
            @Override
            public void onMessage(Map<String, String> headers, String body) {
            }
        }));
    }
```

And be careful in websocket [weberknecht library](https://github.com/pelotoncycle/weberknecht) is bug in **WebSocketHandshake class** in method **verifyServerHandshakeHeaders** is on the line 124 is check only *if(!headers.get("Connection").equals("Upgrade"))*  and when server send *upgrade* instead of *Upgrade* you get error *connection failed: missing header field in server handshake: Connection* you have to turn off ignore cases *if(!headers.get("Connection").equalsIgnoreCase("Upgrade"))*

Comment: My server also have path to SEND messages (chat broker). So how can I send something to it with that solution?

Comment: I will try explain solution for AsyncTask the same you can do it in Services. First you have to create Activity/Fragment, after you call AsyncTask and in phase doInBackground you call my method connection (in previous answered). And you have to import weberknecht library in your project because you call object Stomp which exist in this library thos is everything.  But be careful your server must support STOMP version websocket

Comment: Okay, I got It. Reading code a little bit carefully makes me understand. Thanks!

Comment: Don't forget send PING server, default implementation doesn't send PING and you can get EOF after few doesn't send PING ...it depends implementation on server.

Answer (score 0):

With weberknecht library I had an exception from Spring "*A fragmented control frame was received but control frames may not be fragmented"*.
Fixed it by clearing extra spaces:
**WebSocketHandshake.java**

```
handshake += "";
```

instead of:

```
handshake += "\r\n";
```