# How connect android device to Spring websocket server

Tags: android, spring, websocket

Im trying to  connect android device to the Spring websocke sever. 
But all libs give me errors. Im starting my Spring websocket server on computer and client is in the same network, so im trying to conntect by ip of computer.

**This is sevrer properties**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig 
   extends AbstractSessionWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer<ExpiringSession> {

@Override
protected void configureStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/anveo-appserver").withSockJS();
}

@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
    registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic/", "/anveo/");
    //registry.enableStompBrokerRelay("/queue/", "/topic/", "/exchange/");
    registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
   }
}
```

**And this is example of using my stomp client.**

```
public class StompWebSocketHandler {

private LoggerHelper logger = LoggerHelper.get(this.getClass());

public void connect() {
    StompClient mStompClient;


    mStompClient = Stomp.over(WebSocket.class, "ws://172.26.252.197:8443/app/anveo-appserver/websocket");

    mStompClient.lifecycle().subscribe(new Action1<LifecycleEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void call(LifecycleEvent lifecycleEvent) {
            switch (lifecycleEvent.getType()) {

                case OPENED:
                    logger.log("Stomp connection opened");
                    break;

                case ERROR:
                    logger.log("Stomp connection error");
                    logger.log(lifecycleEvent.getException().toString());
                    break;

                case CLOSED:
                    logger.log("Stomp connection closed");
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
    mStompClient.connect();
}
```

}

**Can anyone tell me what Im doing wrong?**

Answer (score -1):

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37224168/3767355)

Simple example (with [retrolambda](https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda)):

Add the following classpath in project :

```
classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.2.0'
```

Add the following thing in your app build.gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'

android {
       .............
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}


  dependencies {
      ............................
    compile 'org.java-websocket:Java-WebSocket:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.github.NaikSoftware:StompProtocolAndroid:1.1.5'
}
```

For Example :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity { 
    private StompClient mStompClient;
    public static  final String TAG="StompClient";
    @Override 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button view = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        view.setOnClickListener(e->  new LongOperation().execute(""));
    } 


    private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        private StompClient mStompClient;
        String TAG="LongOperation";
        @Override 
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            mStompClient = Stomp.over(WebSocket.class, "ws://localhost:8080/app/hello/websocket");
            mStompClient.connect();

            mStompClient.topic("/topic/greetings").subscribe(topicMessage -> {
                Log.d(TAG, topicMessage.getPayload());
            }); 

            mStompClient.send("/app/hello", "My first STOMP message!").subscribe();


            mStompClient.lifecycle().subscribe(lifecycleEvent -> {
                switch (lifecycleEvent.getType()) { 

                    case OPENED: 
                        Log.d(TAG, "Stomp connection opened"); 
                        break; 

                    case ERROR: 
                        Log.e(TAG, "Error", lifecycleEvent.getException()); 
                        break; 

                    case CLOSED: 
                        Log.d(TAG, "Stomp connection closed"); 
                        break; 
                } 
            }); 
            return "Executed"; 
        } 

        @Override 
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        } 

    } 
}
```

Add Internet permission in manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

and don't forgot to add "websocket" in your URL.

Comment: You just gave me example from the library page, I saw it, thank you.