# how to connect to spring websocket from android

Tags: java, android, spring, grails

i am using grails 3.1.1

i already try to find some documentation and question like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24346068/set-up-a-stomp-client-in-android-with-spring-framework-in-server-side).

this is my code in `ChatController`

```
class ChatController {

    SimpMessagingTemplate brokerMessagingTemplate
    def corporateUserService
    def index={

    }

    @MessageMapping("/chat")
    @SendTo("/queue/chat")
    protected String hello(DestinationUser map) {
        brokerMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend "/queue/chat", map
    }
}
```

and i already deploy this application, for example :

> https://somedomain.com

how can i connect from android to my webapplication's websocket?

i tried

> wss://somedomain.com/chat
>   wss://somedomain.com/queue/chat

but it still cannot connect.

i am trying follow this tutorial [github](https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync)

like this..

```
AsyncHttpClient.getDefaultInstance().websocket("ws://satubangau.com/app/hello", null, new AsyncHttpClient.WebSocketConnectCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(Exception ex, WebSocket webSocket) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onCompleted: ");
            if (ex != null) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }
            webSocket.send("a string");
            webSocket.send(new byte[10]);
            webSocket.setStringCallback(new WebSocket.StringCallback() {
                public void onStringAvailable(String s) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onStringAvailable: I got a string: " + s);
                }
            });
            webSocket.setDataCallback(new DataCallback() {
                public void onDataAvailable(DataEmitter emitter, ByteBufferList byteBufferList) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onDataAvailable: I got some bytes!");
                    // note that this data has been read
                    byteBufferList.recycle();
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

but i get the log like this..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a WebSocket client library on Android, e.g. https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync ?

Comment: i already deploy my app, but it test from http://www.websocket.org/echo.html , it cannot to my websocket..why?

Comment: So it works with http://www.websocket.org/echo.html but not with your web app? Is the path correct for your domain? Are you able to connect to your web app from a browser e.g. on desktop?

Comment: no... i cannot connect from http://www.websocket.org/echo.html to my website... for example, my domain is `example.com` with `https` so my site's address is `https:/example.com` then in my code, i use this code `@MessageMapping("/chat") @SendTo("/queue/chat")` ......so how can i connect from http://www.websocket.org/echo.html to my socket's site?

Comment: i tried using `ws://example.com/chat` and `ws://example.com/app/chat` and `ws://example.com/queue/chat`, but it still not connected