# Suggest me to retrieve real time data from websocket server

Tags: android, websocket, stomp

I am currently working on an GPS based project, I am currently using volley to receive data from web but recently they plan to upgrade the services with real time data. so web developers have programmed the server using websocket, and for browser application they said, they are using stomp.js protocol for retrieving  data from server. They requested me to retrieve data from their server (Real Time Data) use any, but I don't know what will be the best suitable method to get real time data from websocket. I found one example from github https://github.com/NaikSoftware/StompProtocolAndroid but  it's not enough for me to learn, and documentation for using stomp are not enough on internet. I hope there could be better implementation in android.

Please any help and suggestion would be appreciated. Please don't mention me firebase because I have already mentioned them about firebase and they refused to use it. Please guys help me, suggest me or give me one good example to simply retrieve data from websocket server using volley..

Comment: `, I was using volley to parse the data from web` ??? Volley does not parse data. Volley just sends or receives data to or from web. Please rephrase your problem as you used the word parse more than once.

Comment: @greenapps sorry for my bad English!!

Comment: How server communicate to client. is it topic wise communication or just message passing?

Comment: @VinayakB  just message passing, in short one way data passing from server to client and client needs to print data. That's all. Help me

Comment: Okay. In that case I will write 2 answers for you . Stomp specific and normal websocket. Please wait

Comment: @VinayakB Thanks man where will you answer, I will be waiting for an answer..

Comment: refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24346068/set-up-a-stomp-client-in-android-with-spring-framework-in-server-side?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My answer is based on the comments in this question. Don't have enough information on the question so I am writing 2 solution for your question

> Solution 1 - Without using Stomp Implementation- Simple websocket

This is a simple Websocket implementation. for this you can use [koush/AndroidAsync](https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync) library

implement this project into your project

```
    dependencies {
    compile 'com.koushikdutta.async:androidasync:2.+'
}
```

then connect to Websocket server

```
 String url="ws://172.17.1.54:8000/";
    AsyncHttpClient.getDefaultInstance().websocket(url, "my-protocol", new WebSocketConnectCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(Exception ex, WebSocket webSocket) {
            if (ex != null) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }

            webSocket.setStringCallback(new StringCallback() {
                public void onStringAvailable(String s) {
                    System.out.println("I got a string: " + s);
                }
            });
            webSocket.setDataCallback(new DataCallback() {
                public void onDataAvailable(DataEmitter emitter, ByteBufferList byteBufferList) {
                    System.out.println("I got some bytes!");
                    // note that this data has been read
                    byteBufferList.recycle();
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

here setStringCallback() & setDataCallback() will receive your real time update.

You can also use [codebutler/android-websockets](https://github.com/codebutler/android-websockets) library for this.

> Solution 2: With use Stomp implementation

For this you can use [Gozirra](http://www.germane-software.com/software/Java/Gozirra/) java library for solving  this problem.
You can [download](http://www.germane-software.com/archives/gozirra-client-0.4.1.jar) client library.then put it into your libs folder.

For connecting to your server

```
 Client c = new Client("server url", port, "login", "password");
```

Create a listener for the updates

```
 Listener listener=new Listener() {
            @Override
            public void message(Map map, String s) {
                //Do your stuff
            }
        };
```

Then Subscribe to your topic messages

```
 c.subscribe("foo-channel", listener);
```

If you want to unsubscribe you can use below code

```
  c.unsubscribe("foo-channel", listener);  // Unsubscribe only one listener
```

or

```
 c.unsubscribe("foo-channel");   // Unsubscribe all listeners
```

For disconnecting client

```
c.disconnect();
```

I didn't test this with a real server .But I think this will work.Please let me know if it solves your problem

> Solution 3

As you mention the library https://github.com/NaikSoftware/StompProtocolAndroid 
You can use this. simplify version is as follows

Add maven link into your project level gradle

```
  repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
```

Add dependency in your module level gradle

```
 implementation 'com.github.NaikSoftware:StompProtocolAndroid:1.1.5'
 implementation 'org.java-websocket:Java-WebSocket:1.3.0'
```

Then use following code for getting message

```
 StompClient mStompClient = Stomp.over(WebSocket.class, "ws://10.0.2.2:5000/");


    mStompClient.topic("/topic/general").subscribe(new Action1<StompMessage>() {
        @Override
        public void call(StompMessage stompMessage) {
            Log.e(TAG, stompMessage.getPayload());
        }
    });
    mStompClient.lifecycle().subscribe(new Action1<LifecycleEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void call(LifecycleEvent lifecycleEvent) {
            switch (lifecycleEvent.getType()) {

                case OPENED:
                    Log.e(TAG, "Stomp connection opened");
                    break;

                case ERROR:
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error", lifecycleEvent.getException());
                    break;

                case CLOSED:
                    Log.e(TAG, "Stomp connection closed");
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
    mStompClient.connect();
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer but my url is 192.168.1.76:8080/websocket-backend/socket/ and I need to subscribe(/topic/notification") but in solution 2 I don't  have option to pass /websocket-backend/socket/ after port. And the first method it gives me error at onCompleted method() with error "Method does not override it's supperclass." Please help me bro. I am testing server similar like here https://www.stackextend.com/angular/websocket-with-spring-boot-and-angular/

Comment: put 192.168.1.76:8080/websocket-backend/socket/ as server ip in second solution

Comment: Log says "Unknown url 192.168.1.76:8080/websocket-backend/socket" , For example  I have used like  Client c = new Client("ws://192.168.1.76:8080/websocket-backend/socketl", 8080, null, null);  I think because in this case  our  url will be  like 192.168.1.76:8080/websocket-backend/socket:8080 and again subscribe url. :P , I tried passing null at second paramerter(port) but it is an compulsory parameter. what  can I do sir? Can you please  test the code?

Comment: Try  c = new Client("ws://192.168.1.76/websocket-backend/socket", 8080, null, null);  .if its not worked then I will update my answer.

Comment: No bro, not working, same error "No address associated with hostname"!!

Comment: Okay. I will update my answer. please wait

Comment: waiting for an answer

Comment: I edited.  Please check

Answer (score 6):

Use Square's OkHttp library.

Add this dependency to your build gradle

```
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
```

Use below class for listening of webshockts

```
public class SocketListner extends WebSocketListener {

    private Mediator mediator;

    private static final int CLOSURE_STATUS = 1000;
    private WebSocket webSocket = null;

    public SocketListner(Mediator mediator) {
        this.mediator = mediator;
    }

    @Override
    public void onOpen(WebSocket webSocket, Response response) {
        super.onOpen(webSocket, response);
        this.webSocket = webSocket;
        mediator.onConnected(webSocket, response);
    }

    public void sendMsg(String msg) {
        if (webSocket != null)
            webSocket.send(msg);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(WebSocket webSocket, Throwable t, @Nullable Response response) {
        mediator.onFailure(webSocket, t.getLocalizedMessage());
        AppCons.printTag("Failure :", t.getMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void onClosed(WebSocket webSocket, int code, String reason) {
        mediator.closingOrClosed(true, webSocket, reason, code);
        AppCons.printTag("Closed :", reason);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClosing(WebSocket webSocket, int code, String reason) {
        mediator.closingOrClosed(false, webSocket, reason, code);
        AppCons.printTag("Closing :", reason);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(WebSocket webSocket, String text) {
        mediator.getMessage(text);
    }

    public interface Mediator {
        void onConnected(WebSocket webSocket, Response response);

        void getMessage(String msg);

        void onFailure(WebSocket webSocket, String reason);

        void closingOrClosed(boolean isClosed, WebSocket webSocket, String reason, int code);

    }

    public WebSocket getWebSocket() {
        return webSocket;
    }
}
```

Use the below code for accessing the data through shocket

```
private OkHttpClient client;
private SocketListner listner;
private void startShocketConnection() {


    client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().readTimeout(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();

    listner = new SocketListner(new SocketListner.Mediator() {
        @Override
        public void onConnected(WebSocket webSocket, Response response) {
            Log.d("Connected :", response.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void getMessage(String msg) {
            try {
                Log.d("Received", msg);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(WebSocket webSocket, String reason) {
            //reconnect when failure with server
            Log.d("Failure :", reason);
        }

        @Override
        public void closingOrClosed(boolean isClosed, WebSocket webSocket, String reason, int code) {
            Log.d("ClosingOrClosed :", isClosed ? "Closed" : "closing");
        }
    });

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("your shocket url")
            .build();
    client.newWebSocket(request, listner);

}

private void closeSocket() {

        try {
            listner.getWebSocket().cancel();
            listner.getWebSocket().close(1000, "Good bye !");

            if ((response != null)) {
                client.dispatcher().executorService().shutdown();
                client.connectionPool().evictAll();
                response.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        response = null;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your time to answer, I will look at  it  shortly and reply it back!! ;)

Comment: I have edited my ans, as I forgot to provide close socket.

Comment: Not working bro.. is this  code tested? I have so any errors.

Comment: Yes, I have using in my app.

Comment: I think your  code is working, not sure as I already mentioned that I do not have knowledge on spring, hibernate, but I tried connecting to  localhost url "localhost:8080/api/v1/ws", I don't get any connect message but if I change url to "ws://echo.websocket.org" I am getting connected message, the connected only message is not enough for my testing. can you please update your answer with simple server demo for this example?? I'll accept this an answer.

Comment: if you have any server ip then then tell me, i will be happy to help, Meantime you can check this link for detailed knowledge https://googleweblight.com/i?u=https://medium.com/@ssaurel/learn-to-use-websockets-on-android-with-okhttp-ba5f00aea988&hl=en-IN